# Setting up router with APIView and viewset in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

It's my first question on Stackoverflow !

I'm new to Django and following some tutorials.

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to set up the routing of an API from different view classes like APIView and viewsets.ModelViewSet (please tell me if I do not use the good wording)

**In views I have :**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from post.models import UniquePost
from .serializers import UniquePostSerializers
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class UniquePostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UniquePostSerializers
    queryset = UniquePost.objects.all()

class FileUploadView(APIView):
     some code here but no queryset nor serialized data...and no model
```

**In urls I have :**

```
from post.api.views import UniquePostViewSet
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from post.api.views import FileUploadView

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('UniquePost', UniquePostViewSet, base_name='uniquepostitem')
router.register('demo', FileUploadView, base_name='file-upload-demo')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

But it seems that I can register FileUploadView this way. Because I don't have a queryset to render.

I have : AttributeError: type object 'FileUploadView' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

I realized that (well I think) that I can use `APIView` for `FileUploadView` (and add "`.as_view()`) but I think I have to rewrite `UniquePostViewSet` using `APIView` as well and defining exactly what I want to see in details like POST, PUT etc...

My question is : Is there a way to use `DefaultRouter` `router.register` and insert a view that inherit from `APIView` (and a view that inherit from `viewsets.ModelViewset`) at the same time ?

Hope all of this is clear and thank you so much for your help !!!

Answer (score 9):

Something like this should work.

```
from post.api.views import UniquePostViewSet
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from post.api.views import FileUploadView

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('UniquePost', UniquePostViewSet, base_name='uniquepostitem')

urlpatterns = [
    path('demo',FileUploadView.as_view(),name='demo'),  
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UsersViewSet, basename ='users')
```

This happens when there is no queryset attribute in the viewset.